# Can't import custom Python module using Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse

I am writing Python in Eclipse and I have the following problem.
For example, this is the code of my module:

```
class HalloWelt:
    def __init__(self):
        self.A = "Hallo"

    def Antwort(self, strPlaintext):
        print strPlaintext
```

I have saved it as **ex1**. When I try to import this module from another script, I don't see it in the Autocomplete list.

I have also tried to inherit it like this:

```
import ram 
class aa(ram.HalloWelt):
  ram.A
```

but after writing **ram.A**, it is not showing anything starting with **A**. Does anyone know what the problem is? Thank you.

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698/is-there-an-ide-that-provides-code-completion-for-python)

Comment: Are you just having problems with autocomplete, or do you have errors on import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is with autocompletion of `import`, try to do the following in PyDev [Eclipse], assuming you have default settings of PyDev.

Go to `Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Completion.`

1) Change `Minimum number of chars in qualifier for deep analysis` to 3

2) Check `Request completion on all letter chars and '_'?`

Autocompletion should work fine!

Comment: thanks...i dont have enough rating point to vote it up..please dont be offended....

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. I solved it by using another IDE for Python: [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/)
The Community Edition is free and it's already good. If you need some more tools there are business plans you can subscribe.

Comment: The answer can not be just to switch to another IDE.

Comment: Well that's how I managed to solve the problem. The Eclipse plugin PyDEV is poorly maintained. There are tons of requests for autocomplete implementation in PyDEV since a lot of time but they didn't included it (at least not since when I switched to PyCharm). I do not see any other solution tbh.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one project reference another eclipse project in Properties > Project References. That can help a little. It looks like ram doesn't have an A value either. ram.HalloWelt.A might be what you are looking for.

If your module isn't importing then you can add the path to your python path. Example of adding the parent directory below.

```
PARENTDIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(FILE)))
if PARENTDIR not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(PARENTDIR)

import module
```

Comment: more strategic one...i want to vote it up for nice learning. but i dont have enough rating...i am new here...so thanks for helping again